# Is there a framework for reverse geocoding and then getting a list of nearby retail stores?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, reverse-geocoding

Is there a framework for reverse geocoding and then getting a list of nearby retail stores? My meager attempt of looking on GitHub didn't yield any promising results, perhaps someone here knows better?

Comment: There isn't. You need to use 3rd party APIs like Google + Foursquare.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for reverse geo-coding. I'm not sure about getting a list of stores though.

Comment: Yes, I found that out when I searched other Qs before posting this one. The critical point here is to find a framework that does both.